# Where should methods performing small, very specialised tasks be placed?

Tags: c++, oop

This question has been bugging me in the last couple of quick coding challenges I've done.

I have a class called Hourglass, which takes a `char` representing a capital letter in its constructor (e.g. 'D'), and has a method `print()` which prints something like:

```
AAAAAAA
 BBBBB
  CCC
   D
  CCC
 BBBBB
AAAAAAA
```

Print looks then something like:

```
void Hourglass::print() const
{
    final int centreCol = (mFinalChar - 'A');

    for(char c = 'A'; c <= mFinalChar; ++c) {
        std::cout << computeLine(centreCol, c - 'A', c) << std::endl;
    }

    for (char c = mFinalChar - 1; c >= 'A'; --c) {
        std::cout << computeLine(centreCol, c - 'A', c) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

with:

```
std::string computeLine(int centreColumn, int initialBlankSpaces, char characterToPrint) const;
```

Where should `computeLine()` be? Should it be a private member of the class (it doesn't need any information contained inside the object)? Should it be in an anonymous namespace outside the class? Should I avoid such methods somehow?

I am aware this might be a somewhat opinionated subject, but I am sure there is at least some debate towards which I can be pointed to to make up my mind.

Comment: _"Should it be in an anonymous namespace outside the class? "_ I'd choose this option. But your question isn't concisely answerable, it's most likely to get opinionated answers.

Comment: I would be surprised to look at the `Hourglass` class and find such a private member function. Hence, I'd put it outside the class.

Comment: If `computeLine` is only ever called from within that `print` function then consider an anonymous lambda scoped to that function.

Comment: If it's invoked only by other functions of the same class, then it can be declared `private`.

If it's invoked only by other functions of inheriting classes, then it can be declared `protected`.

If it doesn't need any information contained inside the object, then it can be declared `static`.